# is it possible to restrict file type only for pdf and exel file type in webdynpro abap file uploader?

Tags: abap, webdynpro

I am trying file uploder in webdynpro abap but I want it  for some file types like .pdf and .xls only.Actually I have to enhance my existing webdynpro code for this.

Comment: Please provide some code. How do you want to upload the file?

Comment: now I got the answer..thanks for your response.
I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have compare file Mime type with required MIME type..
for ex..
for pdf MIME type is : application\pdf
compare this with uploded files mime type.